# Nashorn: ClassFilter security risk

Tags: javascript, security, nashorn

I am having issues with nashorn and I saw that there is this security flaw:
https://mbechler.github.io/2019/03/02/Beware-the-Nashorn/

when someone can just instantiate a code through this command:
`this.engine.factory.scriptEngine.eval('java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("whatever")')`

and indeed it effects my site.
How can I workaround through it?

Comment: Don't eval user input? If you're worried about security, that's the very first step anyway.

Comment: I do want to allow the user use `eval`. I just want to restrict him from exploiting this bug. I know it can be done using security manager, but I don't know how to append it to the current engine instance.

Comment: `System.setSecurityManager(yourSecutiryManager)`, assuming you don't already have a security manager preventing it.

Comment: @cHao and how is it related to the class loader?

Comment: Among other things, it lets you prevent creation of a new class loader. But what's more important is that it lets you prevent the lower-level things, like network capabilities, file access, creation of subprocesses, etc. So even with a different class loader, or if they trick the existing one, they still can't do the disallowed stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The article tells you.

> Note that the logic, added in the security path, prevents access to
>   `engine` only when there is **BOTH** a `SecurityManager` and a `ClassFilter`
>   present. Reporting this to Oracle, it was stated that this is the
>   intended behavior.
>
> So, even after the patch for CVE-2018-3183, if there is no
>   `SecurityManager` active, the `engine` property will be available to all
>   scripts, even if there is a `ClassFilter` not allowing any access to
>   Java classes at all.

Securitywise, a `ClassFilter` alone isn't enough.  You need a `SecurityManager` as well. The code that provides the `engine` property is only disabled when both are present.

(From the look of it, any security manager will do -- even one that allows everything.  But for security's sake, or if you actually *want* to allow access to `this.engine` for some reason, you probably want a subclass of `SecurityManager` that at least rejects attempts to spawn subprocesses or replace the current security manager. Frankly, it might be better to throw by default, and whitelist things you want to allow.  You probably don't want users to arbitrarily write files, accept network connections, etc either.)

Once you have such a security manager, you'd set it in charge by saying `System.setSecurityManager(yourSecurityManager);`.

Comment: but how can I use the security manager to prevent that single action of creating a new engine and use it like this: `this.engine.factory.scriptEngine`? I so that there is also a mention to that issue here: https://github.com/javadelight/delight-nashorn-sandbox/issues/73 but their solution is not clear.

Comment: The code that returns a value for `engine` checks for the existence of a `ClassFilter` and a `SecurityManager`, and only returns the engine instance if either is absent..  It's not the security manager that prevents access to `this.engine` -- it's the *very existence* of a security manager at all.

Comment: When an instance of my program raises it has a `SecurityManager` which I load like this: `System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());`. Then when I create the `engine` I create it like this: `this.scriptEngine = NashornFactory.create(new ScriptClassLoader(script.getDependencies()));` - looks like I have `SecurityManager` and `ClassFilter` but I still have this security bug.

Comment: What version of Java are you running?  Only the latest versions even care about whether a `SecurityManager` and `ClassFilter` exist, apparently. But this is part of why i was talking about having an actual security manager rather than a do-nothing one.

Comment: is there a way I can prevent just acces to `this.engine` ? I have the latest java version that I'm using.

Comment: ...Have a `ClassFilter`, a `SecurityManager`, and a version of Java that's been patched to resolve CVE-2018-3183. I'll leave it to you to determine whether that applies to the version you have, as you haven't shared it.